# Paypal express checkout redirect to pay with credit card

Tags: paypal, express, checkout

It seems that Paypal has been slowly rolling out a new experience for its customers. In the new environment passing SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole (and LANDINGPAGE=Billing) no longer works properly.

We've tried to contact Paypal numerous times on this issue however it's been extremely difficult to get in touch with an individual who can solve the problem (or even knows what we mean).

Does anyone know of any workarounds to get this functional again?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very unfortunate change they made and didn't bother telling anybody.  I have lots of clients who are pretty upset with it because we integrated Express Checkout specifically because we could force the full credit card form and now that has gone away.

As a PayPal Partner I do have contacts over there who can get things done, and I was able to have them revert some of my clients back to the original flow so it works how they want. This isn't something that they'll do for just anybody, though.

If you want to [contact me directly](http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) I'd be happy to discuss the details with you and see if we can get them to help you out.